# What's the point of building a list with a non-list tail?

Tags: list, emacs, lisp, elisp, cons

The [Emacs lisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rearrangement.html) states about the function nconc that:

> Since the last argument of nconc is not itself modified, it is reasonable to use a constant list, such as '(4 5), as in the above example. For the same reason, the last argument need not be a list

And indeed I can write

```
(setq x '(1 2 3))
=> (1 2 3)

(nconc x 0)
=> (1 2 3 . 0)
```

but that yields a totally broken list:

```
(length x)
=> eval: Wrong type argument: listp, 0

(butlast x)
=> butlast: Wrong type argument: listp, 0
```

- How can I retrieve the original list? `(reverse (cdr (reverse '(1 2 3 . 0))))` doesn't cut it either.
- In which contexts is this a useful pattern? In the standard distribution some functions in `minibuffer.el` use it, in particular `completion-all-completions` and the like.

Comment: BTW, using a literal datum, like `'(1 2 3)`, as a non-last argument to `nconc` is not technically okay. Literal datums are supposed to be considered constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not "broken" lists; they're actually known as *improper* lists (as opposed to `nil`-terminated lists, which are *proper* lists). Many list functions, such as `length` and `butlast` that you just named, expect proper lists, and `listp` returns true only for proper lists.

Improper lists are used in association lists (where the associations are often not proper; though the alist itself must be proper).

---

If you want to make an improper list proper, you have two options:

- Remove the "improper" element.
- Treat the improper element as the last element of the proper list.

Here's a procedure I wrote called `properise` which will do the former:

```
(defun properise (x)
  (let ((r nil))
    (while (consp x)
      (push (pop x) r))
    (nreverse r)))
```

(If you want the latter behaviour, add `(unless (null x) (push x r))` just before the `nreverse` line.)

Comment: Thank for you answer! Is there a simple equivalent to `butlast` for improper lists?

Comment: There isn't, but I edited the post to add a `properise` procedure, which will turn your improper list into a proper list. You can then call `butlast` on that.

Comment: Thanks. That's a pretty tricky procedure. I wonder why `completion-all-completions` returns its results like that.

Comment: Ah, apparently `last` works with improper list, so there's a way to properise without making a copy. I've added it below.

Comment: @Clément Your version should probably have an `n` prefix since it's destructive on the incoming list (which means you have to use `copy-tree` first if you're dealing with literal data). :-) My version doesn't modify the input list which makes it okay to use with literal data.

Comment: FYI, `listp` returns true for improper lists as well. If you look at the source code it just checks whether the given object is a cons or nil.

Comment: @Radon Of course, you are correct. I will edit this post later.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I would avoid creating data structures like that, where the last element is a cons cell with some object other than NIL in the cdr... It makes debugging harder, it's a hack, makes code more difficult to understand, ...

Comment: I agree, as does the OP. In fact, the OP is trying to figure out why `completion-all-completions` in Emacs (sometimes) returns improper lists....

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: Right, and that it hard to figure out, is even more showing that something possibly 'clever' like that should be avoided. Actually I can't directly remember any Lisp software which uses something like that...

Comment: I totally agree. Many lisps have these types of pitfalls. In some, having `(setq x
'(1 2 3)) can cause problems as it isn't a *proper* list and you should do (setq x
(list 1 2 3)) instead

Comment: @TimX `'(1 2 3)` is a proper list. However, it's a literal, which means you are not supposed to modify it, and you may encounter undefined behaviour if you attempt to. `(list 1 2 3)` is a fresh list which you can freely modify.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: is that undefined behavior also in Emacs Lisp?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yes, your right. I should have been clearer.
I believe '(1 2 3) is OK in emacs lisp and you can modify it (many of
the examples of list modifications in the manual do this). It is undefined behaviour
in CL though. BTW the *inpropper* or dotted list does have a purpose, for example
circular lists, but then of course length, reverse etc don't make sense on such lists

Comment: @RainerJoswig It's just as undefined as in CL. Try running this function three times: `(defun fun () (nconc '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)))`. (Okay, maybe don't actually run it, but you can imagine what that does. Same behaviour on Emacs as on SBCL and quite possibly every other CL system.)

Comment: @TimX Modifying literal data isn't okay in Emacs Lisp either (see the example in my previous comment). I don't know about the CL world, but in the Scheme world, circular lists are considered distinct from improper lists (and distinct from proper lists, of course).

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: undefined does not mean some specific behavior. Undefined means 'undefined'. It's not clear what it actually will do and it may do different things at different times. For example in CL it is allowed to share literal data. Thus changing might be possible, but in some implementation it may change data in different 'places', depending on compiler settings (space = 3)...

Comment: @Rainer I 100% agree. My point is that what you see in Emacs Lisp is bad enough already that people shouldn't write code that modifies literal data, and is certainly not "OK in emacs lisp" (quoting Tim's comment).

Comment: In some CL implementations, modifying a literal list will give unexpected/unpredictable behaviour. I'm not sure that is true in emacs lisp. It may still be bad style, but it may not result in undefined behaviour. The reason I suggest it might be OK is that nearly all the examples in the elisp manual on modifying lists use literals. So either it is acceptable or the manual is badly misleading. The example of `(nconc '(1 1 2) '(4 5 6))` maybe not a good example as compiler will likely do the expected thing (though this may depend on the optimisations applied).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unsure why this is a good pattern, but here's an easy way of getting a proper list out of an improper one, without making a copy:

```
(defun nmake-proper-list (x)
  (let ((y (last x)))
    (setcdr y nil)
    x))
```